# Does Apigee Advanced API Services support great than or less than query

Tags: apigee

Is there a way to query a collection in Apigee Advanced API (App Services) using greater than, less than or between kind of constructs?

E.g. in SQL format something similar to

```
SELECT *
FROM geo_ip_table    WHERE ip_lower BETWEEN 12345679 and 12345680
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use any of these operators: =. >, >=, <, <=

The operators are all documented here: http://apigee.com/docs/api-baas/content/supported-query-operators-data-types